# TypeScript: Mapping Enum value to enum key in an utility

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum of this type:

```js
export enum StateEnum {
  STARTING = 'starting', 
  RUNNING = 'running',
  STOPPING = 'stopping', 
  STOPPED = 'stopped', 
  DELETING = 'deleting',
}
```

And I have a DTO object like this:

```js
export class MyDTO {
   public state: StateEnum;

   constructor(infoFromApi: any) {
    const stateAsStringFromApi: string = infoFromApi.state;
    this.state = // Here I am looking for a way to map the stateAsStringFromApi of type string into the corresponding key in the StateEnum. 
  }

}
```

As an example:

Say from API I am getting like `infoFromApi.state` as 'running'.

In my DTO model `MyDTO` I want to expose it as StateEnum such that whoever is receiving the DTO can check different states like this:

```js
case (dtoObj.state) {
  switch StateEnum.RUNNING: // do something
  switch StateEnum.STOPPED: // do something else
}
```

How can I achieve this reverse mapping for TypeScript enum where I can pass the string value and I will get the corresponding enum key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately string enums do not have a reverse mapping that is generated by TypeScript, but you can still create a function to find the key of the enum that matches the value, and if it doesn't match, throw an error:

```
function asStateEnum(string: string): StateEnum {
    const key = Object.keys(StateEnum).find((key) => StateEnum[key as keyof typeof StateEnum] === string);

    if (!key) throw new TypeError(`'${string}' is not a member of StateEnum.`);

    return StateEnum[key as keyof typeof StateEnum];
}
```

Then in your class, you can use this function to convert the string to the enum type:

```
export class MyDTO {
    public state: StateEnum;

    constructor(infoFromApi: any) {
        const stateAsStringFromApi: string = infoFromApi.state;
        this.state = asStateEnum(stateAsStringFromApi);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzsAouaBvAUFXsAqAggEr4CSAcgOJQC8UARAM6IBOcAliAOYMA0OPMQCqFCpRr0GrMCBBdeAvAQDyABTUS6jFgHsADvoX9BuGPnVqUAEW3M4B-cAAmJ5dZQAZFOWp3nwAA2wJw8JgC+WFgAZrIAxpy6IFAITPBIqOgAFCysCgBcULkKAJSF6chokFDYynFJLFAA1sAAntoqAEYAVsAJAHQtrUxZFZmQJf3RXM5ZWUMldAB8sIiV6ADaQylMzW260VBwrU4HqxlVEAC6dLT0xTwlANxRyhyHWQCEC0cAFqy6ADuUBAwGB+BOqFYANYWQABgByAAkGAe3HCCKgHF2IF0cBSUAgwAgnWArCgZzGl36cOerzwrBCYFYySpm22qT2rTOx1OhzZkCuL0iWGAAA99Lp2FA4oFUrsALKtawWGqmKD6MCdQIcOJFNbAcoGy4vdX1EC5MAJKVZLjRXQAMQBEEIRkKCBArUWtWUeHNjRYGUIaTgeR4Tt0Lrd+rD3G0dsdztdHH6geQL19eDgv2xqYN2lSAogOQNwfgsYjUY4dOUkUiQA)

Comment: Thank You.
However only one question I have:
When at the receiving side, I am printing the `typeof state` the type I am getting as `string`. Not getting the `StateEnum` type.
Can I able to check now the StateEnum.RUNNING etc state on the receiving side?

Comment: @Pradip Sorry, I don't understand. Why not just print `this.state`?

Comment: It's string "running" only.
  constructor(ontapSvmInfo: any) {
    this.state = this.asStateEnum(ontapSvmInfo.state);
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  private asStateEnum(string: string): SvmState {
    const key = Object.keys(SvmState).find((key) => SvmState[key as keyof typeof SvmState] === string);
    if (!key) throw new TypeError(`'${string}' is not a member of StateEnum.`);
    return SvmState[key as keyof typeof SvmState];
}